# Oracle SQL: Representing each thousandth of a number with char

Tags: sql, oracle, character

Im new to Oracle SQL and Im having a trouble with this little problem. Is there a way how to represent each thousandth of a number with one '*' char? Lets say I have a number 5000 and the output will look like '****', 1250 '*', 560 ' ', 2200 '**' etc. I was looking into TO_CHAR() function but I cannot find anything ussable. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try that:

```
SELECT RPAD(' ',1+TRUNC(my_number/1000),'*') FROM DUAL;
```

- [`RPAD`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions140.htm) will add as much as `*` as needed for the string to have the required length.
- Please note the string `' '`. It does contain one space (hence the `1+TRUNC(...)`). It is required as Oracle treats empty string as `NULL`. And passing `NULL` as first argument of `RPAD` will return `NULL` without further processing.
- Corollary to the precedent point, your result will have a leading space. You could remove it using `SUBSTR(... ,2)` *but* still as Oracle treats empty strings as `NULL`, this will produce a `NULL` result for values lower than 1000.

---

As an alternate solution, if your values have a not-to-high upper bound, maybe a solution based on [`SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) worth considering:

```
SELECT my_number, SUBSTR('*****', 0, TRUNC(my_number/1000)) FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,
case when id >= 5000 then '*****' 
     when id >= 4000 then '****' 
     when id >= 3000 then '***' 
     when id >= 2000 then '**' 
     when id >= 1000 then '*' 
     else                 ''  
end from t1;
```